# Is it possible to produce Kafka messages containing serialized generic (unknown) C# objects and deserialize them by inferring type in the consumer?

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka

EDIT: From the initial comments, it seems I may be barking up the wrong tree. I initially suggested using replication, but according to the networking team that is not possible because the two databases are on different virtual networks. It doesn't seem like this sort of thing would ever be "impossible", but I don't have the in-depth knowledge required to "fight back". Is there anything specific I should look into regarding SQL replication over the internet/different virtual networks, or points that I could bring up?

I've got an application that uses EF to save changes to an MS SQL database. For reasons, I need to be able to capture all changes made through the application and commit those exact DB changes to another, remote MS SQL db, using Kafka as the communication hub. The solution contains a ton of data entities, so ideally I'm looking for a generic way to capture these changes from the application and apply them to the remote DB where appropriate. The consuming application that is reading the messages from Kafka will also be applying the changes via EF (at least for my purposes).

So, is it possible to do something like this without having to strongly type everything for my hundreds of entities? What are the best practices for doing such a thing? Do I produce messages containing the new entity and the change state (added, updated, deleted)? I'm sure it's a bad idea for some reason, but what about serializing the entire EF ChangeManager and sending that, consolidating all of the Add/Update/Deletes and allowing us to make only a single call vs a bunch?

If I need to provide any more information please just let me know, I'll be monitoring this thread closely.

Comment: `using Kafka as the communication hub.` why? SQL Server already has multiple types of replication - both transactional and snapshot based, both synchronous and asynchronous. EF is an ORM, not a data access library so capturing changes in EF won't capture changes made by any code that doesn't use EF. Given that ORMs play a very specialized role, there will be a *lot* of methods that use ADO.NET directly

Comment: `What are the best practices for doing such a thing?` Don't do such a thing to begin with. You won't be reinventing the wheel, you'll be reinventing a sports car starting from rolling logs. Replication is far more complex than capturing some SQL statements and replaying them. Kafka is orders of magnitude slower than any database replication mechanism. Even if you don't want to use replication, the correct level to do what you want is the database, not high-level client libraries

Comment: For example, you can use change capture in all supported versions and editions of SQL Server to detect changes and collect them, including DELETEs. After that you can copy the modified data to another database and apply them. Of course, that doesn't handle changes made to the target by others

Comment: Yes, I already suggested Replication and MS SQL Server Sync... for reasons, that will not work. The databases are hosted completely independently of each other and not accessible. My dev team immediately suggested this, and the IT/Network team pushed back and said it was not psosible.

Comment: What are the reasons? Because what you just asked won't work either, for the same reasons. Especially if you introduce a system with high latency that can lose updates. `The IT/Network team pushed back ` what will they do when you end up sending even more messages?

Comment: Ok... based on these comments already I'm going to push back and insist we revisit replication...

Comment: You'll have to completely change the architecture of your application if you want to replay messages. Because that's the only thing that makes sense. EF is too low for this, you need to replay the business events. That's the concept behind DDD and Event streaming. You'll have to rewrite your application to make modifications only through events that are replicated to other systems *and* applied to the database. This isn't a bad architecture, on the contrary, it's used for really complex systems. On the other hand, it's a *lot* of complexity for simply applications

Comment: Check Martin Klepmann's [comparison of Event Streaming and Stream Processing with Kafka](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/01/29/event-sourcing-stream-processing-at-ddd-europe.html). Notice that the use case is LinkedIn which has a *huge* load. You can't have 100-way database replication after all. With just two nodes though, Kafka is probably overkill and definitely not worth rebuilding an application

Comment: "The new database we are using for the application and the old database that we need to maintain for reporting services are on different virtual networks". That's what I'm being told... is that able to be overcome?

Comment: Tell them to open a firewall channel and route between the networks? If they cannot connect the networks, then even Kafka isn't going to work